# Turn off console quick edit mode in node.js for windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows

The windows console feature "Quick edit mode" which is enabled by default in Windows 10 is problematic for node.js scripts running with console output because if the user highlights any text in the console, the node process will pause before the next console.log command.

How can a node.js script disable quick edit mode? I have come up with one method that involves invoking an external executable (c++ source, compiled with mingw) but maybe someone knows of a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The method I was able to use was to invoke an external executable which would turn off quick edit mode. When invoked with child_process.exec, based on my testing it remains off for the remainder of the console lifecycle unless the user explicitly re-enables it.

Here is my c++ source:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    HANDLE hInput;
    DWORD prev_mode;
    hInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleMode(hInput, &prev_mode);
    SetConsoleMode(hInput, prev_mode & ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);
    cout<<"The quick edit mode stopped." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I build this with mingw-w64, making sure to select static libgcc, static libstdc++, and static linking to produce a windows executable named stop-quick-edit.exe which only depends on system dlls (kernel32.dll and MSVCRT.dll).

Then I use the following javascript code within node.js to invoke it:

```
async function stopQuickEdit() {

    //assume exe has been copied to same directory
    let execPath = path.resolve(path.dirname(process.execPath)); 

    let result = false;
    try {
        result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            exec(`"${execPath}\\stop-quick-edit.exe"`, {timeout: 5000}, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
                if (error) {
                    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
                    resolve(false);
                }
                
                console.log(stdout);
                resolve(true);
            });
        });
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.error(`Error with stopQuickEdit: ${err}`);
    }

    return(result);
}

...

// to use it:
await stopQuickEdit();

// after this quick edit should be off for this console unless the user explicitly re-enables it
// you can console.log without worrying about suspending the script execution
```